# WPF TreeView With Two Seperate ItemsPanel for Branches and Leaves

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I'm creating a graph with a TreeView.  Below is a screen shot.  So far everything is done with styling.  I'm setting the TreeView's ItemsPanel to a horizontal StackPanel.  *(The paper clips are just place holders for items without an image.)*

[image: Screen shot of tree view graph]

Notice the bottom level children are Leaves.  They do not have any children themselves.

**Here is the question**:  I want those items to go into a separate WrapPanel.  The problem is an item can obviously have children with children and children without children *(Branches and Leaves)*.  The ItemsPanel still needs to be a StackPanel so you get a nice horizontal layout.  But the last control in the StackPanel needs to be a WrapPanel with all of the childless children.

This is a screen shot I pieced together to show the Leaves in a WrapPanel.

[image: Screen shot of tree view with wrap panel]

**Things I have tried**

I've tried to create my own items panel converter, but that converts the entire items panel to a wrap panel.

I've tried to just add a separate tree view to the ItemTemplate and bind it to a separate collection, but that is not the correct look.

**Something I haven't tried**

The WrapPanel I'm talking about is almost like a branch.  But the branch itself is empty, but contains children.  Maybe I could change the style of the node based on a property.  Then instead of showing a picture or whatever, it's data template would be a WrapPanel

Comment: Can you post the xaml of your treeview? What about use a style trigger fired on #_of_children == 0 or fired on a property of your model called IsLeaf or similar. On trigger fired you change the ItemsPanel.

Comment: that's fine @michele, so then what?  A leaf won't use an items panel anyways.  A leaf is in an items panel though.  But I can't simply change the items panel for the parent.  The parent basically needs 2 items panels.  One for branches and one for leaves.

Comment: @michele you made me think of something though.  What if made flag on a node like "IsLeafCollection" and it would change the items panel to a WrapPanel.  Let me see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. I looped through my hierarchical data set and made some changes.  For each branch, I removed its leaves and added them to a new node.  Then I add the node back to the branch.  It sort of creates a place holder.
2. The node contains a property called "IsLeafCollection".  It just verifies that each of its children do not have any children.
3. I have a data trigger that binds to IsLeafCollection.  If it is true, then it changes the items panel to a wrap panel.

Below is a screen shot of the final outcome.

[image: Screen shot of tree view]